# Display Insert,update and delete query statement in message box dialog

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010

I am using Datagridview to insert,update and delete data. i want that, in every apply changes there is a message dialog that will display the commands i made.

Like for example in mySql Workbench in every apply changes there is always a message dialog that displays all the commands that you had made.

Ex. 
Assuming that this will be the message box.

```
UPDATE `inventorysystem`.`tblprices` SET `Price`='2000' WHERE `PriceID`='1';
DELETE FROM `inventorysystem`.`tblprices` WHERE `PriceID`='2';
DELETE FROM `inventorysystem`.`tblprices` WHERE `PriceID`='3';
INSERT INTO `inventorysystem`.`tblprices` (`PriceID`, `Price`, `StockModel`) VALUES ('5', '999', 'Rio fun');
INSERT INTO `inventorysystem`.`tblprices` (`PriceID`, `Price`, `StockModel`) VALUES ('6', '500', 'ruby');
```

Comment: How about storing each .CommandText on a listbox? Then make something with it that looks like a dialog.

Comment: MsgBox(cmd.CommandText)

Comment: Thanks for the idea Guys. I am now creating a dockablewindows as an output window.

Comment: hello guys. now i have difficulties now. im wondering now how to use .commandtext with this procedure. try to look at.